# How to make an array of dots and paths with Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, abstract

How can I create an array or 'node net' of randomly sized shapes, with thin paths between them and dots where each path meets another path?

[image: Lines and dots connecting to make an unidentifiable shape]

Comment: That is a *really* unclear image. Do you have a better one?

Comment: No sorry, I searched for a long time, but because I don't know what it's exactly called, it's hard to find something. But if you enlarge the image it's ok to see, what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

It would be fairly straight forward in Illustrator although **not** automated.

You could draw the paths with the **Pen Tool** however you want them. Then draw a small circle and place it at the intersections.

Conversely, you could place your dots wherever you want them, then use the Pen Tool to draw lines between the dots.

There's nothing automatic or "magic button" in Illustrator which would create this for you.

Comment: no need to draw the dots separately. just use circular arrow heads on both ends of your lines

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to have these arrowheads at each anchor point?

Comment: There exists a voronoi (delunlay is the dual of voronoi) script that does this.

Comment: Voronoi seems not to be the thing I am searching for: [image I found](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2UdLAE_VgU4/UQ3grmo2MHI/AAAAAAAAEoY/4xHNn0lBAdU/s1600/voronoi.png). Do you have a Link to this script?

Comment: "Isn't there a possibility to have these arrowheads at each anchor point?" No, but if you press "P" for the pen tool after every two clicks and move your pen ever so slightly you will be creating separate lines in Illustrator instead of one continuous line. You could then select all the individual lines and add the arrow heads to all of them at once.

Answer (score -1):

You can create it using http://dmesh.thedofl.com/ and import the results into illustrator.

Comment: But as I understand this software, it turns photos into wallpapers made of triangles. I really wanted to create triangles just with lines and dots, like in the image above ;)

Comment: I think you can just bring in a black background and customize how you do the triangles. It will draw the lines automatically. That's what I've done for similar work http://www.istockphoto.com/vector/thumbs-up-on-colorful-mosaic-with-triangles-47684674?st=71868b8

Comment: Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR4DPfgNhs8

Comment: Unfortunately if I load color image in Mesh, then the program doesn't create any triangles.